# What is a singleton select/query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, azure

What is a Singleton Select or Singleton query?

I've seen this for the first time in azure. They say that Azure Data Warehouse is not suited for high volumes of singleton selects.

I tried to search about it and looks like singleton selects terminology is very used in oracle. But perhaps they are as simple as a query that returns a single value.

I also have seen a dispute of cursors vs singleton select, like which of them are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton query is one that returns no more than one row, which is common in OLTP workloads. There is also a scalar query, which returns a single row and column.

Not sure about the dispute between singleton queries versus cursors you mentioned but set-based processing is generally preferred over RBAR cursors in relational databases so that queries can be better optimized.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for the information! I was familiar with scalar queries but not with singleton ones. As I came from back-end development (C#, Java) I initially pictured singleton queries with other colors! I also prefer set based approach over procedural approach! Did't knew that Acronym (RBAR) though, a lot of fun with it! Cheers